# Perl script stucks on 'Deep recursion on subroutine'

Tags: perl

I have perl file `build_ios.pl` with 10-20 methods.

When I run on my build machine `/usr/bin/perl /Users/snaggs/scripts/build_ios.pl`, I get an error:

```
Deep recursion on subroutine "main::writeLogAndPrint" at /Users/snaggs/scripts/build_ios.pl line 179.
Deep recursion on subroutine "main::af_exit" at /Users/snaggs/scripts/build_ios.pl line 167.
```

Here are relevant methods that error point to:

```
sub writeLogAndPrint
{
    my $command = shift || "";

    open(my $fh, '>>', $VERBOSE_LOG_FILE_ABS) or  # line 167
        af_exit(%ERROR_CODE_12);
        #die "Can't open the file: $!";
    print $fh getTimeLoggerHelper() . ": " . $command."\n";
    close $fh;
    print $command . "\n";
}


sub af_exit
{
    my %_error = @_;
    writeLogAndPrint($_error{'id'});  # line 179
    exit($_error{'id'});
}
```

And script stucks on this errors. My build machine uses version `v5.18.2`.

Locally I run same code and everything works fine `v5.16.0`.

Whats wrong with my code and how to get rid of this?

**[EDIT]**

I noticed that  `af_exit` calls `writeLogAndPrint` and `writeLogAndPrint` can call `af_exit` again that can lead to infinite loop

Thanks,

Comment: I'd suggest with `open` to employ fairly direct error handling. Otherwise you may loose error information in `$!` and such -- those are good pretty much _right_ after the error happened.  Afterwards they may get overwritten or blanked by following operations. At least, get them right away and pass them to error handling routines.

Comment: You need to put something like a `$called_from_exit` switch in `writeLogAndPrint` *OR* a `$called_from_writeLog` switch in `af_exit`. It seems clear that you're not opening your file, thus calling `af_exit` and then calling `writeLogAndPrint`, not opening that file again, and calling `af_exit`. On the balance, I would prefer a `$called_from_writeLog` flag in `af_exit`. That way you know not to call that sub in `af_exit`.

Comment: You should be using `die` instead of calling `af_exit`. Wrap your main script in an `eval BLOCK` to catch exceptions and have it call `af_exit` on exception. Then, replace `writeLogAndPrint($_error{'id'});` with `eval { writeLogAndPrint($_error{'id'}) };`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within your `writeLogAndPrint` sub your are trying to open a logfile ... and if that fails you call `af_exit` which calls `writeLogAndPrint` again ... There is the loop.

Check your `$VERBOSE_LOG_FILE_ABS` variable where you want to open the logfile.

Answer (score 0):

Add a helper function to break the cyclic resursion.

```
sub _af_exit
{
    my %_error = @_;
    exit($_error{'id'});
}

sub writeLogAndPrint
{
    my $command = shift || "";

    open(my $fh, '>>', $VERBOSE_LOG_FILE_ABS) or
        _af_exit(%ERROR_CODE_12);
        #die "Can't open the file: $!";
    print $fh getTimeLoggerHelper() . ": " . $command."\n";
    close $fh;
    print $command . "\n";
}

sub af_exit
{
    my %_error = @_;
    writeLogAndPrint($_error{'id'});
    _af_exit( @_ );
}
```

For more information on recursion, see [A Look at Recursion](https://lookatperl.blogspot.ca/2012/11/a-look-at-recursion.html).